# Coinbase HTTP Request for Ether Spot Price

Tags: http, bitcoin, ethereum, coinbase-api

I can currently issue the following request: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD and receive a json response with the current (spot) price of BitCoin (BTC).

What I want is to retrieve that information for Ether (ETH).  I note that the HTTP request that I am using does not specify BTC, it just defaults to that.

I have reviewed the Coinbase API without success in locating an answer.

I was just wondering if anyone is aware of an HTTP request to obtain that data, or if this request is not currently supported via HTTP.

tia

Comment: Thank you David, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Not sure why I was unable to locate the calls you provided in your response, apparently I didn't look long enough and/or in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Coinbase API docs, https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price    shows the following URI structure for getting the spot price for Bitcoin (BTC) or Ethereum (ETH), which is different from what you have posted.

`https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/:currency_pair/spot`

The part of the url indicated as ***:currency_pair*** is a string containing 
the symbol for the coin, a hyphen and then 'USD', such as `BTC-USD` or `ETH-USD`.

I am able to get BTC and ETH spot prices from the api with the following:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/spot